# UIToolBar does not draw at bottom of iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uitoolbar

I want a UITableView with a UIToolBar at the bottom of the screen that does not scroll.

I created a custom UIToolBar in IB.  (I use Xcode 4, so is it still IB?)  Anyway, I linked the `toolbar` instance variable in IB, therefore it's instantiated once the nib is loaded.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customToolbar" owner:self options:nil];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:toolbar];  //toolbar is IBOutlet instance variable
}
```

But it draws at the very top of the screen and is partially cut off by the status bar.

Do I need to customize setting its frame?  Or is there a better way?  I thought the default was to position the UIToolBar at the bottom.

Here's my IB configuration:

[image: IB Config]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want a UITableView with a UIToolBar at the bottom of the screen that does not scroll.*

What would probably work better in this situation is to create a "parent" UIView that contains both your UITableView and your UIToolBar, positioned one above the other and with no overlap (that is, the UITableView leaves room for the UIToolBar below it).

I'm guessing you ended up with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` in your code after trying to add your toolbar as a subview of your UITableView, which resulted in the UITableView scrolling your toolbar off the screen. For better results, use the approach above.